# Update Variable After Calculation in Function - Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a simple calculator with tkinter, the calculation part is fine. The problem is the variable (answer) not getting updated after calculation.

You can see in the window, result label is empty as it's initial value.
[tkinter window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkpJ0.png)

This is the code I used:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as messagebox

answer=""
root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x300")
root.title("Simple Calculator")


def calculate():
    value_1 = value_1_entry.get()
    operator = operator_entry.get()
    value_2 = value_2_entry.get()
    
    if operator=='+':
        answer = float(value_1_entry.get()) + float(value_2_entry.get())
        print(answer)

    
    elif operator=='-':
        answer = float(value_1_entry.get()) - float(value_2_entry.get())
        print(answer)
        
    return answer
    

##################Labels###############
value_1 = Label(root, text='Enter first value', font=('bold', 10))
value_1.place(x=20, y=30)
value_1_entry = Entry()
value_1_entry.place(x=150, y=30)

operator = Label(root, text='Enter the operator', font=('bold', 10))
operator.place(x=20, y=60)
operator_entry = Entry()
operator_entry.place(x=150, y=60)

value_2 = Label(root, text='Enter second value', font=('bold', 10))
value_2.place(x=20, y=90)
value_2_entry = Entry()
value_2_entry.place(x=150, y=90)

#################Results####################
result = Label(root, text='Result:', font=('bold', 10))
result.place(x=20, y=120)
result_ = Label(root, text=answer, font=('bold', 10))
result_.place(x=150, y=120)

##################Buttons###############
calculate = Button(root, text="calculate", font=("bold",10), bg="white", command=calculate)
calculate.place(x=70, y=140)

# Run
root.mainloop()
```

I cant figure out how to make answer="" get updated to new answer in tkinter window, result label.

Comment: `answer` is a global variable, but you're modifying local variables when you do `answer = <something>` in your `calculate` function. Use `global answer` to update the global reference instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update label text using `Label.config() method`.

> **Syntax** : Label.config(text = your_text)

```
result_.config(text=answer)
```

in your case for example:

```
if operator == '+':
    answer = float(value_1_entry.get()) + float(value_2_entry.get())

elif operator == '-':
    answer = float(value_1_entry.get()) - float(value_2_entry.get())

result_.config(text=answer)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply update the label inside `calculate()`:

```py
def calculate():
    value_1 = value_1_entry.get()
    operator = operator_entry.get()
    value_2 = value_2_entry.get()

    answer = None
    if operator=='+':
        answer = float(value_1_entry.get()) + float(value_2_entry.get())

    elif operator=='-':
        answer = float(value_1_entry.get()) - float(value_2_entry.get())

    if answer:
        print(answer)
        result_['text'] = answer  # update result_ label

    return answer
```